# how can i change the sharepoint web application name and it also apply in IIS?

Tags: 2010, iis, alternate-access-mapping

In SharePoint 2010, when I create new web applications I gave the name of SharePoint web applications like sharepoint-81,sharepoint-82... and after application created, in IIS also name of the applications created like below.

- sharepoint-81
- sharepoint-82

Here I am facing difficulties in IIS I can not found which application related which hostname,

Here how can I change the SharePoint web application name and it also applies in IIS?

AAM for these web apps:

- Default: http://spwf1:81
- Intranet: http://hostname

[image]

Comment: check this one http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/how-to-change-sharepoint-web-application-name-and-url.html

Comment: it has two things, first update the name in Sharepoint then manually change in IIS. I jsut tested and its worked

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The ServerComment property is a read only value. Instead, you will need to delete the Web Application (and thus it will delete the IIS Site), then recreate it with the name you desired.